# USB Device not recognized (error 43, arduino uno)

Tags: arduino-uno, usb

I know that there's already post about this, but mine is different. Instead of not recognized, it gets recognized, and I can upload codes, but after a while, windows starts to not recognize it. And there is a temporary fix for this for my laptop, I need to restart. And even after restarting, it still becomes not recognized after a while

Edit : forgot to mention, even if it is not recognized, it still sends power to the arduino

Comment: Genuine Arduino board, or a cheap Chinese knock-off?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a genuine arduino board. Also, this just happened recently, I had this board for over 5 months now, and this just happened

Comment: It sounds like the USB chip is dying. I would expect that from a Chinese clone, but not a genuine Arduino.

Comment: Does the USB chip get hot?

Comment: The USB Chip does not get hot

Comment: Are you using a USB hub, or plugging it in direct to the laptop?

Comment: I plug it in directly to the laptop without any other external stuff...Still, I guess I should try other cable first and then I'll see

Comment: "both of them has the same problem." sounds like it's a problem with your computer, USB cable, or with something you're connecting to the Arduinos.

Answer (score -1):

The USB microcontroller Atmega16U2/Atmega8U2 on the Ardunio UNO board might be corrupted. Try uploading the USB to Serial HEX file with boot-loader found in C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr\firmwares\atmegaxxu2\Arduino-COMBINED-dfu-usbserial-atmega16u2-Uno-Rev3.hex
using Flip OR any other other ardunio (as an ISP programmer). for doing this you have to first enter BOOT-LOADER by shorting the Reset Pin of the USB controller to GND  both pins can be found on ICSP2 of the UNO.
This will surely solve the issue.
But,
if the problem still persists then your USB controller is damaged and have to replace the controller and again upload the USB to serial firmware, the process is same as mentioned above, but you don't need to short reset and GND as you don't have an boot loader installed in the new controller.

Comment: I can confirm that this cannot be the case. As I have two arduino boards lying around and both of them has the same problem. I don't think both of them could get damaged at the same time. But I might try this option